# CRM Plugin Registration for SetState & SetStateDynamicEntity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When I register my plugin on SetState & SetStateDynamicEntity nothing gets executed.  When I register update the code executes properly but Update is unreliable for the business process I have.  Any ideas why registering 2 steps on SetState & SetStateDynamicEntity wouldn't be triggering?
[image]

Comment: are you sure they don't get executed? synchronous or asynchronous? which entity? did you debug the plugin or used trace?

Comment: They don't execute, I have the debugger attached to the process.  It's a custom entity.

Comment: synchronous or asynchronous? if is a custom entity, you need to execute this code when a record is deactivated or activated?

Comment: synchronous, I need it to run when it's deactivated.

Comment: at this point post a screenshot of the plugin registration tool of the configured step

Comment: Thanks for the help!  How do I share a screenshot?

Comment: edit your post or use a service like tinypic.com and post the url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35026/discussion-between-user1842828-and-guido-preite)

Comment: Use SetStateDynamicEntity (tbh I cannot remember the reason why, but it'll work!)

Answer (score 0):

Your registration looks sound (we have some plugins that run on the SetStateDynamicEntity so I know that that works, so I'd probably abandon the SetState Message.  We also have it on the pre-validation step instead of the post, but I can't believe that that would be an issue).  So that leaves your with a couple of possibilities

- You're not updating the state of the `img_workflow` step to active or inactive, resulting in the plugin never getting triggered.  Change your plugin to immediately throw an exception, refresh it, and then deactivate or active an img_workflow.  You should see your exception
- The plugin is executing, but you're not seeing it do anything.  Again, changing your plugin to an exception would help in trouble shooting for this.
- You're registering it in a different Org or environment than what you're testing in.

It's got to be one of those three issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try register SetStateDynamicEntity and check for "EntityMoniker" in the context instead of "Target".

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("EntityMoniker") &&
    context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"] is EntityReference)
{
    var myEntity = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"];
    var state = (OptionSetValue)context.InputParameters["State"];
    var status = (OptionSetValue)context.InputParameters["Status"];
 }
```

Hope it helps.